# Should I use become: true on every task that requires root permissions

Tags: ansible

I have a small open-source ansible role([selivan/ansible_ipmi_lan_manage](https://github.com/selivan/ansible_ipmi_lan_manage)) and recently I got a pull request that adds `become: true` to all tasks that require root permissions, that are almost all tasks in that role.

Should I accept it or should I keep the code concise and expect user to import this role with `become: yes`, because it obviously can not work without root permissions?

Comment: Tough call .. but gut feeling for me is to not accept the PR and put the onus on the user to manage privilege escalation in their own way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If any tasks should NOT be run with `become: true`, the PR could be necessary; ie. if certain tasks should be run as `ansible_user` when `ansible_user != root`, you would not want `become: true` to be applied to those tasks.

Comment: Only tasks that should not use root are local tasks(to generate files on local machine, not on target host) and they are already marked with `become: no`. So I decided to decline the PR.

Comment: That makes sense to me, @SelivanovPavel